# Mongo shell methods throwing "not a function" error in express app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to get some information about my mongoDB database and DB server, in my express app.
I am using 3 mongo shell methods as given below.

```
app.get('/api/server-info', async function(req, res)
{
  var dbVersion = await client.db("MSSMTDB").version();
  var dbHostInfo = await client.db("MSSMTDB").hostInfo();
  var dbStats = await client.db("MSSMTDB").stats(); 

  var obj =
  {
    "dbVersion": dbVersion,
    "hostInfo": dbHostInfo,
    "dbStats" : dbStats
  };
  res.json(obj);
});
```

Link to documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-database/#database-methods).

Unfortunately, only the db.stats() method is working for me and the other two functions are throwing "is not a function error".

After some investigation I found that my mongodb nodejs driver version is '3.1' and could not find the version() and hostInfo() methods in its documentation. Even the upcoming version (4.0) does not seem to have these functions.

Any solutions for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that [Db class](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Db.html) from MongoDB Node.js driver doesn't have methods `version()` and `hostInfo()` corresponding to Mongo shell

Please consider the following alternatives depending on your needs:

1. Use [Db.command](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Db.html#command)

```
const dbHostInfo = await db.command({hostInfo: 1});
```

2. Use [Admin.serverInfo](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Admin.html#serverInfo) or [Admin.serverStatus](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Admin.html#serverStatus)

```
const serverInfo = await db.admin().serverInfo();
const serverStatus = await db.admin().serverStatus();

const dbVersion = serverInfo.version;
```

Comment: Hi @peter. I tried 1st method and it gives CMD_NOT_ALLOWED error

Comment: @JPK, do you use free Atlas tier? If so, the operation might be forbidden: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/unsupported-commands/

Comment: Yes.. I am using the free tier now .. Thanks for pointing out... So I guess the commands will work fine if I run mongoDB on my production server